# PHP can't find class 'GhostMailer'

Tags: php, email, laravel

So i am trying to call some functions of a mailer class..
In phpStorm when i type `GhostMailer::setSender();`

I can navigate to the file when i click my scroll button on the `GhostMailer::` text to where GhostMailer is into, but whenever i run the program it says class GhostMailer not found..

Code for calling

```
GhostMailer::setSender(Input::get('emailfrom'));
GhostMailer::addRecipient(Input::get('emailto'));
GhostMailer::setSubject(Input::get('subject'));
GhostMailer::setHTML(true);
GhostMailer::setMessage(Input::get('email'));
GhostMailer::setReturnAddress(Input::get('emailfrom'));
GhostMailer::getHeaders();
GhostMailer::send();
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: This sounds to me like the class (file) is not actually loaded and therefore the class doesn't exist at runtime

Comment: Thanks for replying but how do i load the file then because i never heard about that @lukasgeiter

Comment: That depends... Is that a class of your own or is it from a 3rd party package? Also where is the file located?

Comment: The class is my own and the file is located in a folder named classes and im using laravel framework.. so the model is located at models ofcourse @lukasgeiter

Comment: Laravel 4 or Laravel 5?

Comment: Laravel 4.2 @lukasgeiter

Comment: Okay. Add `"app/classes",` to the `classmap` array in `composer.json` and then run `composer dump-autoload` and you should be good to go

Comment: Doing it right now and uploading my whole base fresh to my hosting i will report back here! @lukasgeiter

Comment: You're welcome! I put together an answer from the comments so you can accept it and mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like the class (file) is not actually loaded and therefore the class doesn't exist at runtime.

Add `"app/classes"`, to the `classmap` array in `composer.json` and then run `composer dump-autoload` and you should be good to go